# Debian: Where does a bridge interface store its MAC address and how can I change it?

Tags: debian, linux-networking, mac-address, bridged-adapter

I have reinstalled a computer and since I need several similar computers, I duplicated the hard disk with dd. On the target systems I have adjusted `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*` accordingly.

So I got different machines with different host names and different IP addresses.

But while the hardware interfaces also have different MAC addresses, the bridge interface has the same MAC address on all target systems. *Apparently it was copied along.*

The bridge is "classically" defined in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/bridge`:

```
iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports enp0s31f6
    address 192.168.1.20
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

(Needless to say that I set address on each machine individually.)

As a trial I changed the file, removed the bridge interface, assigned the IP address directly to the ethernet interface, rebooted (worked: bridge was gone and the hardware interface had the correct IP address) and edited the bridge back in.

After that the bridge had its original address again...

Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overall behavior is caused by *systemd*, even if *systemd* isn't configured to manage the system's network.

---

A bridge interface on Linux has two "modes" with its MAC address:

- the implicit mode

  When creating a bridge interface without specifying its MAC address, it gets a temporary random MAC address (with private bit set). When an other interface is set as bridge port, the bridge inherits this interface's MAC address to replace the temporary one. I leave undefined what happens when a 2nd interface is added because behavior might have changed depending on kernel version. This mode can't exist anymore on a system with a recent *systemd* running.
- the explicit mode

  When creating the bridge (`ip link add ...`) or changing it (`ip link set dev ...`) one can specify `address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, changing the bridge's behavior: it won't inherit anything, its initial oper state will be *down* when administratively set up (because it has no connectivity yet) instead of *unknown* and a few similar things. For example by indirect effect such bridge won't have a link local IPv6 address created since it's in down oper state, until it has actual connectivity using an added bridge port itself with connectivity.

---

### systemd

Recent versions of [systemd choose to always explicitly assign a MAC address](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/6d36464065601f79a352367cf099be8907d8f9aa) to virtual interfaces that were created without specifying the address (*systemd* tracks this. One can track what it does by running `ip monitor link` and see that the interfaces created without stating the MAC address immediately get their MAC address changed (by *systemd*)). *systemd* doesn't care (at least by default) if it's supposed to manage the interface or not.

This affects bridges. Because the algorithm choosing the MAC address depends on the system's *machine-id* UUID (and the interface name), if the system-cloning actions don't change the *machine-id*, two systems will keep the same MAC addresses on their virtual interfaces with the same name, such as `br0`. These two systems won't be able to communicate properly anymore over their LAN since there must be no same MAC address on an Ethernet LAN (and this might cause some switches in the path to complain and log flapping errors).

This *systemd* behavior is visible in the host initial network namespace but not in other network namespaces (unless they have *systemd* also running on it like would be the case in a system container managed by LXC), because *systemd* won't track other network namespaces.

### Solutions

As *systemd* doesn't look like it will disappear soon, the best way is to stay compliant with what it does: have an unique *machine-id* provisioned on each cloned system. The [method to change the setting for each clone is explained for example there](https://wiki.debian.org/MachineId#line-35) (and is not specific to Debian, but to using *systemd* or one of its sub-components):

> ### machine id and cloned systems, generating a new machine id
>
> The machine id is something that is frequently missed to change when
> cloning a machine. A new machine-id can be generated by
>
> ```
> rm -f /etc/machine-id /var/lib/dbus/machine-id
> dbus-uuidgen --ensure=/etc/machine-id
> dbus-uuidgen --ensure
> ```
>
> Making `/etc/machine-id` a 0-byte file is considered to be the canonical
> way to clear it, rather than actually deleting it, because if systemd
> is running on a completely read-only root filesystem, it has code to
> create a machine ID on a tmpfs and bind-mount it over the top of the
> empty file.

So either execute the 3 commands above and have a way to automate this (eg: using *ansible* which could compare with the deployed id present by default), or just remove files and create an empty `/etc/machine-id` hoping *systemd* will do some randomization (if not R/O, no idea how this later method behaves).

Of course doing a manual assignment of the MAC address won't be overridden  by *systemd*. So as long as the value is different on each system, one can set the address when creating the interface. With the `ifupdown` package and `bridge-utils` installed (because it provides additional functions to `ifupdown`, not really for the obsolete `brctl` command) you can use the function [`bridge_hw`](https://manpages.debian.org/bridge-utils/bridge-utils-interfaces.5#bridge_hw) in the bridge stanza.

You can either copy the real interface's MAC:

```
    bridge_hw enp0s31f6
```

so that for example DHCP without DUID behaves the same as it would have without a bridge configuration, and as an added bonus, defer the choice of an unique MAC address to the hardware (ie: the NIC manufacturer or for virtual systems the hypervisor).

Or you can choose a different MAC address on each system:

```
    bridge_hw 12:34:56:78:9a:bc
```

---

For more details and reproducible examples about this "feature" of *systemd* and how it affects bridges and other virtual interfaces, see this UL SE Q/A where I made an answer:

[How can I make Linux generate different MAC addresses for different bridge devices which are on different PCs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719379/how-can-i-make-linux-generate-different-mac-addresses-for-different-bridge-devic)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on systemd! Unfortunately I found out that `bridge_hw eth0` does not work, probably because I have `ifupdown2` installed, not `ifupdown`, so I had to specify actual address.

Comment: Incredibly good! Many, many, many thanks for this great detailed answer.